# TypeScript: Omit trailing parameter of generic function when its type is undefined

Tags: typescript, generics

Is it possible to configure TypeScript to allow omitting the trailing parameter of a generic function if the trailing parameter's type is `undefined` (but not if it isn't)?

Example:

```
type Events = {
  readonly first: { readonly foo: string};
  readonly second: undefined;
}

const sendEvent = <Name extends keyof Events>(name: Name, payload: Events[Name]) => {
  console.log(`SEND EVENT "${name}"`, name, payload);
}

sendEvent('first', { foo: 'bar'}); // <-- OK

sendEvent('second', undefined); // <-- OK

sendEvent('first');  // <-- Error as expected, Events["first"] isn't undefined,
                     // that's good
sendEvent('second'); // <-- Error: 'Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.'
                     // would like to not have an error here, since
                     // Events["second"] is undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to allow that when `name` is `"second"` and not when it's `"first"`, you can't just use an optional parameter. But you can check if the payload is `undefined`, and if it is, make the second parameter optional by making the second element in the tuple optional:

```
const sendEvent = <Name extends keyof Events>(
    ...[name, payload]: (Events[Name] extends undefined ? [name: Name, payload?: Events[Name]] : [name: Name, payload: Events[Name]])
) => {
```

A bit long but it works, especially if you have more events.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAzlAvFA3gKClAJwgEMATAe0QBsQoAzASwJWAC5tCSLra7zz2LAg0QBzAL4BuPJzKUaUFBADGlUuwCuiUhEaIIpaeJw5ViFoqSl4SYBigAeAHLEAttAgAPYFbQBrCBByOlgEZBQAPgAKGXwAOgSAbUQ3CAAaKDBiECpyMgBddiibcMSXd3yoLx9tNC0dPQMoAH4oZNT2cvTM7NyyZvYS1DLU-Mr2dvdO1IysnLz1UNsUEYr8gEocdYwI7BkzFHIqCDjc0SiAAwBlGCcAEVgANVuAFSgAIgASLBT3cXeLhlft05n1SOsjCYlNohlEAOSMZjAOEZLD0fjsOEAI2IBDh4ghUAA9ETHABaMlQADyAGkoVZYXClGZSCioPVdCIDISSeTKbT6TCwsB4cy1HCeaSHBTqXScNDrML4YiWBLJMSpTKYAQCOQCFBiGgdCgmAYcEA)

Comment: That is a **really** cool trick.